# Can't obtain selected value for AJAX parameter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to pass `id` and `value` of the selected option as parameters to my ajax. Somehow I can see `id` passing but not the value.

How can this be achieved, I am posting my code here, please any advice will be helpful.

I have tried many ways but still the `datString` shows up `Object { id: "3", designationname2: "3" }` on `console.log`.

```
<b>Designation</b>
<select name="designation" class="form-control"  id="desig" >
    <option value="">Select a Designation/Role</option>
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, designation FROM tbl where status =1 and designationtype_id = 1 ");
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $des_id2 = $rows['id'];
        $designationname2 = $rows['designation'];
        echo "<option value=" . $des_id2 . ">" . $designationname2 . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

And AJAX,

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#desig").change(function () {

            var id = $(this).val();
            var designationname2 = $('#desig').val();
            var dataString = {'id': id, 'designationname2': designationname2};
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "escalation_ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#rephead").html(html);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: what was the output you get...?

Comment: check your console log for errors,and show us

Comment: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]
escalation.php:31:13
TypeError: fakewaffle is undefined[Learn More]
escalation.php:472:3
Object { id: "3", designationname2: "3" }`

Comment: This is what I get on console.log

Comment: Do you want to get the designation name from selected option?

Comment: Yes.. I want to pass id and name to my ajax as datastring

Comment: so what was the issue...?

Comment: @Bhargav As you can see `Object { id: "3", designationname2: "3" }`.Want it to be `Object { id: "3", designationname2: "selected option name" }`

Comment: `$( "#desig option:selected" ).text();` try this

Comment: var designationname2 = $('#desig').val(); this gets the value of selected option, if you wish to get selected name then try $( "#desig option:selected" ).text();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change below line

```
var designationname2 = $('#desig').val();
```

This line will get the value of the selected option, that you don't required

to

```
var designationname2 = $(this).find("option:selected").text()
```

Above line will give you text of the selected option of text of the current element.

OR

```
var designationname2 = $('#desig option:selected').text()
```

Above line will give the text of any selector with option selected

Comment: Can you please add this comment in your question and give me some description about this or put another question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var designationname2 = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

Use `text()` instead of `val()`

```
var designationname2 = $( "#desig option:selected" ).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 var designationname2 = $('#desig option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Tried.. But still the output is `Object { id: "3", designationname2: "3" }`

Comment: So what you want to pass then? Any other data? which id you are talking about?

Comment: As you can see `Object { id: "3", designationname2: "3" }`.Want it to be `Object { id: "3", designationname2: "selected option name" }`

Comment: @Ansh you are missing something here. Name should be for select dropdown not option. Option have value only. If you want to pass name of select dropdown. You can try this

Comment: var name = $(this).attr('name); and var dataString = {'id': id, 'designationname2': designationname2, name: name};

Comment: Improve your answer using the edit option. It is better than posting comments.